# Message from the network

Tags: riddle

You guys have to guess both the identity *(name)* and the message, below the hints. Good Luck !

**Identity**

All the hints share the same classification and each hint represent the first letter once solved.

- My name is Gregory, and i am a good man.
- Extraterrestrials are involved.
- Yellow natural liquid.
- Oh my god !
- Just Chuck Norris testing some stuff.

**Message**
5+!11@|\|0@|-|41|#@-1!|#3@3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is

> "Still no Half-life 3" written in 1337, with @ for spaces.

Therefore, the identity is almost certainly

> Gabe Newell, or GabeN.

It may of course be someone else, but that seems unlikely. So let's try to torture the clues until they fit.

My name is Gregory, and i am a good man.

> **G**regory **G**oodman produced the movie The **G**ift

Extraterrestrials are involved.

> **A**liens

Yellow natural liquid.

> **B**ile

Oh my god !

> **E**gads!

Just Chuck Norris testing some stuff.

> [**N**o testing required](https://memegenerator.net/instance/64884112/chuck-norris-approves-no-testing-required-it-will-work), it will work.

Ok, so torturing them yielded a worthless confession with no particular "classification". The Geneva convention may have been onto something.

Since I'm currently without a working knowledge of either the HL universe or movies in general, I think I'll stop here for a moment. Should anyone figure out some better answers to the clues, please do feel free to snatch the sensible portions from this answer.

Comment: Nice work, you got the message and the identity even if the answers to the hints are wrong (all of them :P).
The hints are the name of memes the title of the riddle itself is "Message from the network " : International network = Internet.
1. Good Guy Greg
2. Aliens
3. Bear Grylls
4. Eh mah gerd !
5. Nope! Chuck Testa

Comment: @AnouarBelkadi what do you mean, all of them? The second one is spot on! :-)

Comment: Oh yea true, sorry xD